# PHPUnit - Share login method with Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I write selenium test in phpunit and have a problem with share login code. My tests looks like:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        // Other code in setup
    }

    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->url(my_domain);
        // Actions for input login, password and submit

        // Real testOne 
    }

    public function testTwo()
    {
        $this->url(my_domain);
        // Actions for input login, password and submit

        // Real testTwo
    }

    // (...)
}
```

Many tests and many files, all methods contain login data and login code.
I would like to share that login action beetween all test. But how? I can't add this code to setUp (Selenium error about invalid actions in this method) so I need to run some code before each test, but not in setUp.

Inherit and add my code into constructor? But I still can't use code before setUp, only add short code to all test (ex. parent::login() or something like that).

Comment: What are you trying to do in `setUp` that throws errors?  Depending on your tests it is ok to use `setUp` or `::setUpBeforeClass`

Comment: Go to url, put values into form, submit etc (login action). Selenium says, that is not place for such code.

Comment: can you give the exact code and error you are trying to use ? hard to help with generic info

Comment: I move my code to method setUpPage in new class (inherit by Selenium TestCase and now it works.